# Can I put my 8x plug in a 4x slot (CPU powering)

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply, power

Is that okay or will that damage my hardware?
Because I just got a new power supply (corsair vs650) with a 8x plug but my motherboard (h81m-plus) only has a 4x plug

[image]

Is this fine or am I out of my mind?

Answer (score 1):

The connectors on PSU's now are often 4+4 CPU connectors now. They should look similar to the following:

[image]

The manual for [your PSU](http://www.corsair.com/~/media/Corsair/download-files/manuals/psu/CORSAIR-PSU-MANUAL.pdf) states:

> B. If your motherboard has a four-pin socket, detach the four-pin from
>   the  eight-pin cable, and then plug this four-pin cable directly to
>   your motherboard.

Be sure you're using the right connector, there are other 8 PIN connectors (Often PCI-e 6+2 pin). You are likely using the correct one as they *should* only fit in the correct sockets, but double check for a splitable connector as pictured.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rb2HfqH6gNk) shows what looks like the correct connector at 3:25.